# Invalid policy document. Policy syntax is wrong

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have a rest API resource as such,

```
TempApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-temp-api
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
        VpcEndpointIds:
          - vpce-0cfefxxxxxxxxxxxx
      Policy: !Sub |
        {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow"
              "Principal": "*"
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke"
              "Resource": "execute-api:/*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Deny"
              "Principal": "*"
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke"
              "Resource": "execute-api:/*"
              "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                  "aws:sourceVpce": !FindInMap [Environments, !Ref Environment, VPCEndpointAPI]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Upon deploying I receive the following error:

```
Invalid policy document. Please check the policy syntax and ensure that Principals are valid.
(Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException)
```

Any help in identifying what's wrong with the policy document will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Paras

Answer (score 1):

Just found out I made a silly mistake, missed commas after every key value pair.

Corrected policy:

```
TempApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub ${Environment}-temp-api
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Types:
          - PRIVATE
        VpcEndpointIds:
          - vpce-0cfefxxxxxxxxxxxx
      Policy: !Sub |
        {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
              "Resource": "execute-api:/*"
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Deny",
              "Principal": "*",
              "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
              "Resource": "execute-api:/*",
              "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                  "aws:sourceVpce": !FindInMap [Environments, !Ref Environment, VPCEndpointAPI]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```